# run external command from within vim

Tags: vim

When I run `fc -l -20` in my zsh, I get the expected output.

However when running the same from within vim like so:

`:r! fc -l -20` I get error saying: `zsh:fc:1: no such event: 0`

Why is that, and how to get my previous 20 history list entries into vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fc` is a [shell builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin) and as such would have to be called from within your shell. Alternatives are `fc -l -20 | vim -` or maybe `<c-Z>` `fc -l -20 | pbcopy` `%` `"*p`.

Comment: To clarify for the op, when you call fc from within vim like this vim is spawning a new shell and your invocation of fc is trying to recall the previous 20 commands of this new shell, but there are "no such event(s)"

Comment: But why then, when I spawn new zsh shell instance from say current shell, I still have access to history entries in the parent shell (as they are shared between spawned shells in my zsh setup)?